# Most secure settings for user dedicated for SSH Tunnel

Tags: security, ssh, linux, ssh-tunnel, user-permissions

Due to security reasons, I have created a user on my remote VPS only to use it for SSH tunneling. My local PC goes in hands of many others which scares me because I need to leave that SSH session open. So, I want to lock this user (on server) so that others couldn't do anything other than SSH tunneling (even if password gets compromised). With this user, I only want to login (with password) & do SSH tunneling.. nothing more!
Can you please help?

Comment: @ChrisS oh sorry.. I was on my friend's PC. By mistake, I used the browser in which he logged in. So, you might have encountered same flag message from two accounts.

Comment: This question seems like it might be useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48129/how-to-create-a-restricted-ssh-user-for-port-forwarding

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you use an SSH key to authenticate as that user.

In the .ssh/authorized_keys you can set options about what things that user can do.  For example you could set the `no-pty`, `no-X11-forwarding` options to prevent the user from getting a shell or doing any X11 forwarding.  See the [sshd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) for a full list of options.

If you are not using key-based authentication, and your server is running a fairly recent version of OpenSSH, then use the `Match user` option combined with the options to block access, and force a command that does nothing.  See [man sshd_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config).

```
Match user username
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand /bin/cat
```

Comment: By login, I meant login with password. SSH key based authentication doesn't work with SSH Tunnel app of Android.

Comment: Really?  What a *less than useful* application.

Comment: Instead of /bin/cat, you want http://www.mariovaldez.net/software/sleepshell/

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the initial SSH session/tunnel without RSA keys and the `-L` (bind forwarded address to local address) and `-N` command (do not execute any commands)
ie:

> ssh -L local port:webaddress:port -N

so in your case, since you're forwarding SSH, it might look like...

> ssh -L 22:webaddress:22 -N

This should set you up with the forward, without setting up a session.

[some light watching](http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/quick-and-dirty-ssh-tunneling) and [reading](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html) on this.

Comment: But, its not server-side solution. If my password gets compromised, it can't help. Notice, I have added dedicated user for this task.